# SwingWorker done() called twice?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm doing a `Swing` java program that involves a worker to populate a JTable from a query that was made to a DB, this works fine but when it finishes, I've got in the `done()` method a check to see if any results were processed like this:

```
    public void done() {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            jLabelResultados.setText("Procesados " + tablaResultados.getModel().getRowCount() + " resultados.");
            return;
        }
        try {
            get();
            if (tablaResultados.getModel().getRowCount() == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanelClientes.getParent(), "No se encontraron resultados con los criterios de búsqueda definidos", "Sin resultados", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                jLabelResultados.setText("Encontrados " + tablaResultados.getModel().getRowCount() + " resultados.");
            }

        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Excepcion", e);
        }
    }
```

But my problem is that the pop out when results are zero appears twice, which makes me think that the `done()` method is called twice, but I am unable to find what's the reason for that or the problem with the code.

Here's the full swingworker code for reference:

```
private class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, Object[]> {

    private ResultSet resultado;
    private JTable tablaResultados;
    private DefaultTableModel modelo;

    public Worker(ResultSet resultado, JTable tabla) {
        this.resultado = resultado;
        tablaResultados = tabla;
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultado.getMetaData();
        int columnas = metadata.getColumnCount();
        Object[] etiquetas = new Object[columnas];

        for (int i = 0; i < columnas; i++) {
            etiquetas[i] =
                    metadata.getColumnName(i + 1);
        }
        publish(etiquetas);

        while (resultado.next() && !this.isCancelled()) {
            Object fila[] = new Object[columnas];
            for (int i = 0; i < columnas; i++) {
                fila[i] = resultado.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            publish(fila);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(List<Object[]> chunks) {
        if (modelo == null) {
            modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
            modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(chunks.get(0));
            tablaResultados.setModel(modelo);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < chunks.size(); i++) {
            modelo.addRow(chunks.get(i));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            jLabelResultados.setText("Procesados " + tablaResultados.getModel().getRowCount() + " resultados.");
            return;
        }
        try {
            get();
            if (tablaResultados.getModel().getRowCount() == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanelClientes.getParent(), "No se encontraron resultados con los criterios de búsqueda definidos", "Sin resultados", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                jLabelResultados.setText("Encontrados " + tablaResultados.getModel().getRowCount() + " resultados.");
            }

        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Excepcion", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And when using it:

```
  tarea = new Worker(resultado, jTableResultados);
    PropertyChangeListener doneListener = new PropertyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            if (e.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.STARTED) {
                jButtonCancelar.setEnabled(true);
                jProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            }
            if (e.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                jButtonCancelar.setEnabled(false);
                jProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            }

        }
    };
    tarea.addPropertyChangeListener(doneListener);
    tarea.execute();
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

Comment: hmm ... should work, never seen a done called twice. Argghh, just detected an error in my last answer: the process is loosing rows, the loop should start on the second chunk only for the very first batch of chunks, for all susequent it must start from the first.

Comment: can't reproduce (with or without my bug) - so must be something else, no idea what that "something" could be. Would search for something crazy and totally unexpected, like starting two threads or so.

Comment: What it exactly happens is that when I press the accept button of the option pane, another one pops. maybe this gives another tip??

Comment: no, sorry. For starters, try to find out if they are opened by the same or different workers: f.i. add a name parameter and show that in the optionPane

Comment: ok, added this.toString() on the optionpane not sure if that's what you meant, but it definaltely shows different strings, one was (myclass)Worker@1a47da2e, the other (myclass)Worker@412e4ba3

Comment: sorry, didn't see your last comment until now (remember that it needs a @username guarantee that I'm notified automatically :-) - glad you could sort it out (assuming so from your comment in the other thread, where I got notified because it was my answer :-)

Comment: @kleopatra actually is not sorted out, now I think i know the problem is that there are two different workers but I'm only creating one worker in my code, and the .execute() is done just once so I'm kinda lost

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, had to do something with the code involving the calls to the method that was creating the Worker, there were two different events on a button calling the same method that created the two different Workers

Fixed by removing the most restrictive event.